# const array of func pointers befuddles

Tags: c++, arrays

```
void process( int boat ) { ; }

const void(*sequence_A[])( int ) = { process, process }; //ERROR
const void(**func_sequence)( int ) = sequence_A;

(*func_sequence++)( 7 );
```

Why won't this compile? I want const to refer to the array, not the contents of the array.

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'const void (__cdecl *)(int)'
```

EDIT: So you guys are saying it doesn't exist. Fair enough. Just to be clear, I'm posting this analogy of the functionality I wanted but this is with int instead of function ptrs

```
    //Compiles without error
int number1 = 7;
int number2 = 3;
const int* sequence_B[] = { &number1, &number2 };
const int** numbers = sequence_B;

int check = **numbers++; //value is 7
int chec2 = **numbers++; //value is 3
```

Comment: There is unfortunately no such thing as a `const` array, except in the sense of an array of `const` items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's analyze the meaning of your statement

> ```
>  const void(*sequence_A[])( int ) = { process, process }; //ERROR
> ```

The way I remember the parsing of `*x[]` is that the second argument of `main` is `char* argv[]`, so, it's an array of pointers. In other words, `sequence_A` is to be indexed, and then the result is to be dereferenced.

Then, to that you can apply a function call argument parenthesis with an `int` value, and as a result you should get a …

`const void` ?

Well that's not entirely meaningful. You can have a pointer to `const void`, but you can't dereference that pointer: you can't "get at" the `const void` directly. Yet here is some pointer to a function that *produces as its expression value* a `const void`.

To match that you would need

```
const void process( int boat ) { ; }
```

<del>and although I haven't tried it, I doubt that any compiler will accept it.</del> [**Update**: as it turns out, at least g++ accepts it, so it is one solution. But it's a very unconventional function signature. And not at all what you're after!]

In short, remove that `const`.

---

On a related note, as mentioned already in a comment you can't have a `const` raw array, except in the sense of a raw array of `const` items.

It's a corner case of the language, a problematic type system aberration inherited from C.

Along with the array type decay to pointer, also problematic.

---

**Addendum**: example of how to make the array items `const`:

```
void process( int boat ) { ; }

int main()
{
    void(* const sequence_A[])( int ) = { process, process };   // OK
    //sequence_A[0] = process;     //ERROR
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this functionality is just arbitrarily not available. I did wonder if that was the case.